Short Film about a rich, retiring businessman who is thinking about leaving his business to a young, hard working war veteran who lost his arm
I'm trying to remember the name of an older short film I watched in college. Here's what I remember about it:
The film is in English with american accents. I watched it in the mid 2000s, but I suspect the short film is older, like from the 80s, (or even late 70s).
It's about a young man, who lost his arm in the war, that starts to work for this old, successful businessman. This rich businessman wants to leave his company in good hands. He sees potential in this young man because he is honest, works hard, and is persistent. He devises a test to see if the young man is the right person to leave his business to. However, the businessman's jealous assistant tries to thwart the young man.
I remember part of the test involved the young man using his own money to make lots of phone calls on a pay phone, or something like that.
The moral of the short film was along the lines of never giving up, honest hard work, and persistence.
